# Parameter values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using SSRS to build report. Format of my query is as follows

```
declare @Date  smalldatetime
select @Date = '20140421'

exec API_someAPI
     @DateStart = @Date
    ,@DateEnd = @Date

select ...
where t1.Column < @Date
```

the problem is when enter this code in query editor, to form all necessary parameters, it asks for @DateStart and @DateEnd, but not for @Date. Shortly, it generates two parameteres, but I need @Date parameter, and it does not gebnerate it. I've tried to create it manually, and changed text as follows

```
..
select @Date = @Date
..
```

and created a new parameter, but query didn't work that way. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `declare @Date  smalldatetime; select @Date = '20140421'` creates a **variable** and assigns it a value. If you want a parameter then you don't want `declare @Date  smalldatetime` and presumably the whole point of the param is that it is not a hardcoded value so delete the next line too.

Comment: I see what you mean though the parameter inference from the query editor doesn't work very well both in terms of creating unnecessary parameters and inferring the wrong data types for the parameters. This seems to avoid most issues `DECLARE @DateStart smalldatetime = @Date;DECLARE @DateEnd smalldatetime = @Date;exec API_someAPI @DateStart = @DateStart, @DateEnd = @DateEnd select * FROM sys.objects where create_date < @Date`